# C - while (something || something)

Tags: c

I have a quick question about while loop.

I want to read ASCII char code and if it's not some particular ascii code I don't want to continue and ask user to enter it again.

This works

```
    while (yn != 89)
    {
        printf("\nEnter");
        flushall();
        scanf("\n%c", &yn);
    }
```

This does not

```
    while (yn != 89 || yn != 121)
    {
        printf("\nEnter");
        flushall();
        scanf("\n%c", &yn);
    }
```

**Gosh, I think I need to get some sleep. This was rather... stupid. :)** Thanks guys BTW.

Comment: `||` means "or", `!=` means "is not equal to".  Read the code out loud to yourself and I think you might see the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `yn != 89 || yn != 12` is always true. Any value is either not equal to `89` or not equal to `12`. So, this expression makes no practical sense. The cycle will loop forever, since the repetition condition is always true.

According to your description, the condition you need is `yn != 89 && yn != 12`. `&&`, not `||`.

Answer (score 3):

Your boolean logic is a bit off:

```
while (yn != 89 && yn != 121)
```

Another way to write this, which may be more logical as a "reader":

```
while (!(yn == 89 || yn == 121))
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace || with &&.

The reason:

`!(yn == 89 || yn == 121)` <==> `yn != 89 && yn != 121` (DeMorgan)

Answer (score 1):

When `yn` is 89 it is *not* `121`; similarly when `yn` is 121, it is *not* 89; thus, the condition is always satisfied.

Perhaps you mean while `yn` is not either `89` or `121`, that's phrased with an *and*:

```
while(yn != 89 && yn != 121)
```

or alternatively you can say "when `yn` is neither `89` or `121`":

```
while( !(yn == 89 || yn == 121) )
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little on the other replies - you will never get to your second condition. The first "short-circuits"

`if (yn != 89`

And stop right there. If it's not 89, we're done. We don't care about anything after that in the `if` because `||` (OR) is "If either of these is the case".  And of course, if it IS 89 ... then it's certainly not 121.

You want `while (yn != 89 && yn != 121)`

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of `(A || B)` is `(!A && !B)` and the inverse of `(A && B)` is `(!A || !B)`.  Your thought process in constructing the original loop was something like, "I want `yn == 89`, so I should *invert* that to loop *while* `yn != 89`."  Then you decided to change it to, "I want `yn == 89 || yn == 121`, so I need to invert that."  That's where you went wrong:  From the forms I presented originally you can see the inverse (to use as your while condition) is `yn != 89 && yn != 121`.  You simply extended your original, simple inversion with `||` inappropriately.